# matplotlib drawing dynamic plots from TCP data

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tk-toolkit, python-multiprocessing

For work I use some software for analysing data bus messages and i need to display some of that data in an x,y plot. The software has a python interpreter but unfortunately it doesn't play nice with threads/processes and interactive pyplot's cause it to crash. I thought maybe i could use a localhost TCP server to pass data between the software and an external pyplot process.
Iv'e been hacking my way through some of the simple multiprocessing TCP server/client examples online and have so far come up with whats posted below.

The problem i have is that the figure (although it does update) is unresponsive and that is no good. I tried to play around with running the plot in its own Process and use a global Queue to get the data, but the plot couldn't see the global Queue used by the client thread even when passed as an argument, but i was able to run the plot in interactive mode. Anyway, i abandoned that and iv'e ended up with this.

Can anybody help me fix this or provide a better solution?

**Server.py**

```
import socket
import sys
import traceback
from threading import Thread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
from multiprocessing import Process



class Figure(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        proc = Process(target=start_server, args=(self,))
        proc.start()

    def Plot(self, data):
        f = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        d = json.loads(data)
        print "Plot data: ", d
        f.plot(d[0], d[1], d[2])
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.ion()
        plt.show()
        #plt.show(block=False)
        #plt.draw()


def start_server(fig):
    host = "localhost"
    port = 8888
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    soc.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    try:
        soc.bind((host, port))
    except:
        print("Bind failed. Error : " + str(sys.exc_info()))
        sys.exit()
    soc.listen(5)       # queue up to 5 requests
    print("Awaiting Connection...")

    while True:
        connection, address = soc.accept()
        ip, port = str(address[0]), str(address[1])
        print("Connected with " + ip + ":" + port)
        try:
            Thread(target=client_thread, args=(connection, ip, port, fig)).start()
        except:
            print("ERROR - Thread did not start.")
            traceback.print_exc()


def client_thread(connection, ip, port, fig, max_buffer_size = 5120):

    print "Awaiting Data..."
    while True:
        print dir()
        client_input = connection.recv(max_buffer_size)
        fig.Plot(client_input)
        print("Data Received: {}".format(client_input))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    figure = Figure()
```

**Client.py**

```
import socket
import sys
import json
import random

def Main():
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = "localhost"
    port = 8888

    try:
        soc.connect((host, port))
        print "connected"
    except:
        print("Connection error")
        sys.exit()

    message = json.dumps(([random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)], [random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)], random.choice(["r", "b"])))

    while message != 'quit':
        soc.sendall(message)
        raw_input("Press 'Retrun' to draw plot.")
        message = json.dumps(([random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)], [random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10), random.randint(1, 10)], random.choice(["r", "b"])))

    soc.send(b'--quit--')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: what do you mean by "unresponsive"?

Comment: @georgexsh The Tk window that the figure embeds itself in dies if the window is clicked. Furthermore, when hovering over the window in Windows the cursor changes from a mouse pointer to a loading cursor. Also, there are no x,y coordinates for the cursor position when hovering over the window.

Comment: Seems this is an issue related to Tk, I added Tk tag to the question.

Comment: @georgexsh Thanks, although I'm pretty sure this would happen with a Qt window too, I'll give it a shot to confirm.